# Showing data in AJAX & JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to take data from function "NewData()" and display it in "SomeActionMethod View" by json.
The problem is how to access the data in $.ajax
This is my HomeController file

```
    public ActionResult SomeActionMethod()
    {
        return View(); 
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult NewData()
    {
        List<mydatasample> mydata = new List<mydatasample>(); 

        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test2", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        int rowcount= mydata.Count;

        return Json(mydata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    public class mydatasample
    {
       public string bookName { get; set; }
       public string publisherName { get; set; }
       public int publishYear { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my "Some Action Method View" file. In my $.ajax part what should i do that it must display data in some action method...

```
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function ()
     {
          var hosturl = "http://" + window.location.hostname + ':' + window.location.port + "/Home/NewData";
          console.log(hosturl);
          $.ajax(
          {
              cache: false,
              type: "GET",
              url: hosturl,
              success: function (e)
              {
                  alert('i am in this function');
                  for (var i = 0; i > 10; i++)
                  {
                     console.log(e.mydata[])
                     mydata++;
                  }
            },
            error: function ()
            {
                alert('Failed to retrieve books.');
            }
        });
 });
```

Comment: `console.log(e[i].bookName); console.log(e[i].publisherName);` etc

Comment: console.log(e.mydata[i])

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you explain in detail i am still stuck.

Comment: Your returning a collection, which your assign to `e` - you need to access each item in the collection by its index (and you loop needs to be `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)` - not `i > 10`)

Comment: As a general principle I suggest you learn how to navigate through JavaScript objects (bear in mind at this point your JSON data string has been converted into a Javascript object / array). Lots of tutorials / examples are available which help you understand how to read entries from JS objects.